page tiktok is not available in webView android java
   webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                if (url.startsWith("http") || url.startsWith("https")) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (url.contains("tiktok.com")) {
                    String urlTiktok = url.replace("tiktok.com", "tiktok://user/");
                    try {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlTiktok));
                        startActivity(intent);
                        return true;
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Ứng dụng TikTok chưa được cài đặt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                if (url.startsWith("intent")) {
                    try {
                        Intent intent = Intent.parseUri(url, Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME);
                        String fallbackUrl = intent.getStringExtra("browser_fallback_url");
                        if (fallbackUrl != null) {
                            startActivity(intent);
                            return true;
                        }
                    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view1, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view1, url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view1, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view1, url, favicon);

            }

        });

I have a project that uses WebView to display Tiktok links inside. However, despite trying everything, webView still cannot display TikTok's page. What should I do?
I don't know what to do. Please help me!
How can I to fix it?
